# Styling range input with pure CSS as separation between images

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have two images, and I need to compare them really precisely, so I want to put them one under the other and allow the user to slide the top one to discover the other one under. I decided to use a input range to slide the image.


 I want to style a range input to become the separation between two pics. As you can see on my example fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/up068q4q/55/) I'm pretty close **BUT** I need to fire event with a mouse click on my first image.

I tried to size my input equal to my image but it going over and block mouse event.

I add few rules, the size of my image can change when the window is resizing, and I didn't manage to change the CSS dynamically for range input so I thought pure CSS will be a good solution.

Increasing the height of the thumb (moving part of the range input) look like a good idea but i don't know how to trigger it...

```
$('myInputRange').css('height', pictureSize)
```

Does really not the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` of your overlapping containers is likely the problem here.

I have a [JSFiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/up068q4q/68/) that assigns the onliick to your `slider` element instead, and the function fires.  Also, I copied the JS code below:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('sliderInput');
var main = document.getElementById('mainContainer');

setViewPort(slider.value);

slider.oninput = function(){
    setViewPort(this.value);
}

slider.onclick = function(){
    alert('clicked!');
}

//For sliding
function setViewPort(pourcentage){
var width = main.offsetWidth*(pourcentage/100);
  document.getElementById('containerImgSliding').style.width = width+'px';
}
```

Comment: I can't assign the function to another element that my div below... In fact i don't need only to fire onclick action but a click and drag action that draw a rectangle into.

Comment: Can I prevent event to fire through the track and only use the thumb to change the value on the range input ?

Comment: You may want to look into [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values) to accomplish this.  Without changing the z-index (because it would likely break your slider-object events) you could set the thumb's CSS to `pointer-events: none;`  However, this would prevent your slider-object events entirely.  You may be able to use the `pointer-event values from the link` as a workaround though.

Comment: Sorry but what is the _link_ and _pointer event values_ ? I can manage to gather slider value by another way than the object himself ?